# How do I configure oauth2 in JHipster (release 6.0.1)?

Tags: jhipster, okta

I am trying to update jhipster v5.8.2 to v6.0.1
But I get an compilation error

```
 The Issuer "https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default" provided in the OpenID Configuration did not match the requested issuer "https://login.pomzen.com/oauth2/default"
```

My previous configuration in application.yml is:

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            access-token-uri: https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
            user-authorization-uri: https://login.pomzen.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
            client-id: {myId}
            client-secret: {mySecret}
            scope: openid profile email
            # Token is valid 3 hours
            tokenValidityInSeconds: 10800
        resource:
            user-info-uri: https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
```

My new configuration in application.yml is

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://login.pomzen.com/oauth2/default
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: {myId}
            client-secret: {mySecret}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following for your issuer?

https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default

If you tack on /.well-known/openid-configuration on the end, you’ll see all the endpoints you used to have to specify.

https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I tried to use https://dev-672339.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default and then the code compiles. 
But when I try to login I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/oidc
which ends up in a 404 Page not found error


Note: I want to be directed to a custom login page that has facebook and google social login configured. 

I had that running with the previous configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Okta Authorization Server is configured for your custom domain.
Go to: https://dev-672339-admin.oktapreview.com/admin/oauth2/as

Select your "default" authorization server from the list, then click the **Edit** button.

You should have a dropdown for the **Issuer** which you can select your custom domain from. (make sure this value matches what is in your `application.yml`

Do you have anything custom for your HttpSecurity configuration?

Comment: It works now after following your instructions. I don't think that I have anything custom for my HttpSecurity configuration.